# Compute $\int_{a}^{b}\left|x\right|\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

The reason I ask this is because $$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}\left|x\right|\mathrm{d}x$$  gives exactly the same result as $$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}x\mathrm{d}x=\frac{b^2}{2}-\frac{a^2}{2}=\int_{x=a}^{x=b}\left|x\right|\mathrm{d}x$$ when $0 \leq a \leq b$

But for a non trivial case could someone please show the steps of integration of $$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}\left|x\right|\mathrm{d}x$$ for $-7\le a\le 8$ and $0\le b\le 12$.

Thank you.

Comment: @GudsonChou Okay if I specify that $a\lt 0$ and $b\gt 0$ could you show me the result?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_a^b \lvert x\rvert\operatorname d x = \int_a^0 (- x)\operatorname d x + \int_0^b x\operatorname d x = \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ when $a<0<b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, as per given intervals, we have

1. $a<0$, $b\geq 0$ $$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}|x|dx=\int_{a}^{0}|x|dx+\int_{0}^{b}|x|dx$$

$$=\int_{a}^{0}(-x)dx+\int_{0}^{b}(x)dx$$$$=-\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{a}^{0}+\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{b}$$ $$=\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{b^2}{2}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$
2. $a\geq 0$, $b\geq 0$ $$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}|x|dx=\int_{a}^{b}xdx=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{b}$$$$=\frac{b^2}{2}-\frac{a^2}{2}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If I gave you awkward arbitrary ranges such as $-7\le a\le 8$ and $0\le b\le 12$ could you show me all the steps to compute the integral?

Comment: you can select any arbitrary values of $a$ & $b$ & simply substitute them in the final result of appropriate case 1 or 2 . For example if we have $a=-4$ & $b=2$ then substitute these values in case (1).   If we have $a=3$ & $b=9$ then substitute these values in case (2).

Comment: Okay that's good, now we're getting somewhere. Will you please show me explicitly what you just said in your answer? In other words substitute those values in please so I can understand it better, thanks.

Comment: All the steps are shown in the answer, notice if $a=-4$, $b=2$ then substituting these values in case (1) as follows $$\int_{-4}^{2}|x|dx=\frac{(-4)^2+(2)^2}{2}=10$$   if $a=3$, $b=9$ then substituting these values in case (2) as follows $$\int_{3}^{9}|x|dx=\frac{(9)^2-(3)^2}{2}=36$$

Answer (score 5):

This is not true in general, and depends on $a$ and $b$:
$$\int_{-1}^1 xdx =0 $$
but
$$\int_{-1}^1 \lvert x\rvert dx = 2\int_{0}^1 \lvert x\rvert dx = 1.  $$

What you mention clearly holds if $0 \leq a \leq b$ (since anyway in this case $x=\lvert x \rvert$ for $x\in[a,b]$).

**Edit:**
If $a < 0$, b$>0$, then
$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b \lvert x\rvert dx &= \int_a^0 \lvert x\rvert dx + \int_0^b \lvert x\rvert dx = \int_a^0 (-x)  dx+ \int_0^b x dx = \int_0^a x  dx+ \int_0^b x dx\\
&=
 \frac{b^2+a^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$
while
$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b x dx &= \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will modify my question to see what happens when $a$ and $b$ have different ranges.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Okay that's really helpful, so if I'm understanding you correctly we have to split the integral up to account for the different ranges of $a$ and $b$ is that it? Could you please take another look at my edited question to see if it can be done with those ranges also?

Comment: Basically, yes: depending on whether $x$ is positive or negative in the region (since $\lvert x\rvert$ is then either $x$ or $-x$).

Comment: If I gave you awkward arbitrary ranges such as $-7\le a\le 8$ and $0\le b\le 12$ could you still compute the integral? I ask these questions as I need to know how to deal with the different scenarios.

Comment: You sort of have to know the sign of a and b (more precisely, if they have the same sign or not)

Comment: Are you saying that it cannot be done if $a$ or $b$ are bounded above _and_ below ($-7\le a\le 8$ and $0\le b\le 12$) and that it can only be computed if $a$ and $b$ are bounded above _or_ below ($a \lt 0$ and $b \gt 0$)?

Comment: All I am saying is that the signs of a and b olay a crucial role in the result.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $|x| = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2 (\text{sgn}\ x)}{2}$. Here, $\text{sgn}:\Bbb R → \Bbb R$ is the sign function,

$$ \text{sgn}\ (x) = \begin{cases} +1 & x>0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ -1 & x<0 \end{cases} $$

Thus we see that

$$ ∫_a^b |x| \ dx = \frac{b^2 (\text{sgn}\ b) - a^2 (\text{sgn}\ a)}{2}$$

This formula works for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$. For example, if $a,b>0$ it does indeed reduce to $\frac{a^2 - b^2}{2}$. We also obtain if $0<a=-b$, $\int_a^b |x| \ dx = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}$. These are the special cases given by the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not familiar with $$\text{sgn}\ x$$ Would you care to elaborate please?

Comment: $\text{sgn}\ x$ is the sign of x. I.e. if x<0, $\text{sgn}\ x = -1$, if x>0, $\text{sgn}\ x = +1$, and $\text{sgn}\ 0 = 0$. I will edit the answer to include this.

Comment: Mickep's formula is the same as mine, since $|x| = x \text{sgn}\ x$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way of doing this algebraically is to note that
$$
\int |x|\,dx=\frac{1}{2}x|x|=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}x^2, & x\geq 0,\\
-\frac{1}{2}x^2, & x<0,
\end{cases}
$$
since $D(x^2/2)=x$, which coincides with $|x|$ for $x\geq 0$, and $D(-x^2/2)=-x$, which coincides with $|x|$ for $x<0$. Thus, by the so-called fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
\int_a^b |x|\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\bigl(b|b|-a|a|\bigr).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, will your method and Calvin's still work for bounded intervals above and below such as: $-7\le a\le 8$ and $0\le b\le 12$? If so, how?

Comment: The primitive I gave works for all real $x$ and hence for all real $a$ and $b$. The same with Calvin's. To see that, just divide the primitive in two: For $x>0$ it equals $x^2/2$, and the derivative of that is $x$ which agrees with $|x|$. Dothe same for $x<0$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the word 'primitive' in this context, would you please show me explicitly what you just said by editing your answer? As I'm a confused - sorry, I need you to literally spell it out for me :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you ask for, but nevertheless I updated my answer with an extra detail.

Comment: @BLAZE a primitive $f$ of $g$ is an antiderivative, i.e. a function such that $$\frac{df}{dx} = g $$
we also write this as $∫ g = f + c$